# Why does nil-checking a table view cell property cause one of my cells to copy another?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My table view loads pictures through SDWebImage (async image downloading/cache category for UIImageView) in each `tableView:cellForIndexPath:`.

```
                                               // 'spot' is a dictionary of this cell's attributes
NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString*)[spot objectForKey:@"Image"]];
UIImage* placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
```

^ Loads the images, but is constantly having to make requests or pull from the cache. So I wanted to see if the rendered cells were stored in memory, so I could only make requests for images when I need them. I went about this by adding a simple check for the image property of the image view.

```
if (!cell.pictureView.image)
{
    NSURL* imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString*)[spot objectForKey:@"Image"]];
    UIImage* placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

    [cell.pictureView setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:placeholderImage options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly];
}
```

This works and keeps my images from having to reload after exiting and reentering the application. But in one of my cells that has a purposely bad image url (for debugging), the image- which used to remain as the `imageNamed:@"placeholder"`- is now the same image as my second cell.

I'm curious what kind of cell-reuse/cache magic is causing the cell to take the picture of a previous cell.

What is the best way to retain cell properties and only set them when needed?

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely the issue is with the image package you are using.  If you are making repeated URL requests to grab images, it is probably best practice to implement NSURLCache, which is a fairly simple and handles caching perfectly so it is not an issue.  [This is the NSHipster guide on how to use it.](http://www.nshipster.com/nsurlcache/)  Other solutions tend towards these sorts of issues.  Since it is a category on UIImageView, it could be any number of things causing issues with UIImageView's implementation when getting used in the cell.